# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XX} failed due to the following error: 80004005 Unspecified error

Tags: vb.net, dll, com, dllregistration

I am working on VB.NET WinForm Application ( 32 bit) which references third party COM dll (32 bit). My Target Platform points to x86. I registered the dll using command prompt as administrator. However while creating the instance of dll it intermittently not able to create it and I get the following COM exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0CBDC6C1-3D1E-4CEB-A89E-5D081985E874} failed due to the following
>   error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005
>   (E_FAIL)).

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Can you be more specific about whose DLL this is?

Comment: Hi Eric, The dll is third party COM dll - mom9_api.dll

Comment: That's not terribly helpful; google doesn't yield results for either the dll name or the clsid.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I am running into a similar issue with a 3rd Party DLL